# setInterval and CPU usage in React rendering

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, cpu-usage

I'm making a React-app with some animation inside. Using setInterval every 40 ms, I have an issue with CPU usage (it's about 40-50%). I thought it was because I have too many elements for animation, but then I've tried rendering just one div, which shows a single variable:

```
let min = 0;
timer() {
   this.startTimer = setInterval(() => {
      min += 1;
      this.setState({m: min});
   }, 40);
}
```

And it's still too bad: 20-25% CPU usage for just refreshing 'div', which displays a variable 'min'. Who knows a way to reduce CPU usage when you rendering html-elements in react?

Comment: If you use the setInterval for animation then you can optimise it by using animation libraries. Like CSSTransitionGroups or react-spring. They use either css animation or handle the animation outside react. It is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it.